# Novice question about implementing graphics on a game in Ruby

Tags: ruby, graphics

I have a simple 1 person game concept I want to make a demo for.   I know ruby and basic website stuff, but little else.

The game involves pieces moving around in a 3d cube gameboard.

I can do the back end stuff with Ruby, but how do I go about implementing the graphics?   I would like to be able to move the pieces with a mouse.   So I would have to see the cube game board, the pieces inside, and be able to move the pieces about.  It would also be nice to be able to rotate the gameboard, and zoom in and out, as well as center the view on specific pieces.

Thanks!

Comment: You need a graphics library like Tk, Qt, Fox, or similar for general graphics. You might also use a game-specific engine rather than a general GUI toolkit if you have specific needs.

Comment: There are a lot of Javascript game / graphics frameworks and you can communicate to the backend via AJAX or websockets